# Group by records by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select, group-by

I am using `SQL Server 2008 R2`. I am having a database table like below :

```
+--+-----+---+---------+--------+----------+-----------------------+
|Id|Total|New|Completed|Assigned|Unassigned|CreatedDtUTC           |
+--+-----+---+---------+--------+----------+-----------------------+
|1 |29   |1  |5        |6       |5         |2014-01-07 06:00:00.000|
+--+-----+---+---------+--------+----------+-----------------------+
|2 |29   |1  |5        |6       |5         |2014-01-07 06:00:00.000|
+--+-----+---+---------+--------+----------+-----------------------+
|3 |29   |1  |5        |6       |5         |2014-01-07 06:00:00.000|
+--+-----+---+---------+--------+----------+-----------------------+
|4 |30   |1  |3        |2       |3         |2014-01-08 06:00:00.000|
+--+-----+---+---------+--------+----------+-----------------------+
|5 |30   |0  |3        |4       |3         |2014-01-09 06:00:00.000|
+--+-----+---+---------+--------+----------+-----------------------+
|6 |30   |0  |0        |0       |0         |2014-01-10 06:00:00.000|
+--+-----+---+---------+--------+----------+-----------------------+
|7 |30   |0  |0        |0       |0         |2014-01-11 06:00:00.000|
+--+-----+---+---------+--------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Now, I am facing a strange problem while `grouping` the records by `CreatedDtUTC` column.

I want the `distinct records` from this table. Here you can observe that the *first three* records are *duplicates* created at the same date time. I want the distinct records so I had ran the query given below :

```
SELECT  Id, Total, New, Completed, Assigned, Unassigned, MAX(CreatedDtUTC) 
FROM TblUsage 
GROUP BY CreatedDtUTC
```

But it gives me error :

*Column 'TblUsage.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

I also have tried DISTINCT for CreatedDtUTC column, but had given the same error. Can anyone let me know how to get rid of this?

P.S. I want the `CreatedDtUTC` coumn in `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,101)` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message itself is very explicit. You can't put a column without applying an aggregate function to it into `SELECT` clause if it's not a part of `GROUP BY`. And the reason behind is very simple SQL Server doesn't know which value for that column within a group you want to select. It's not deterministic and therefore prohibited.

You can either put all the columns besides `Id` in `GROUP BY` and use `MIN()` or `MAX()` on `Id` or  you can leverage windowing function `ROW_NUMBER()` in the following way

```
SELECT Id, Total, New, Completed, Assigned, Unassigned, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,101) CreatedDtUTC
  FROM
(
  SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Total, New, Completed, Assigned, Unassigned, CreatedDtUTC 
                                 ORDER BY id DESC) rnum
    FROM TblUsage t
) q
 WHERE rnum = 1
```

Output:

```
| ID | TOTAL | NEW | COMPLETED | ASSIGNED | UNASSIGNED | CREATEDDTUTC |
|----|-------|-----|-----------|----------|------------|--------------|
|  3 |    29 |   1 |         5 |        6 |          5 |   01/07/2014 |
|  6 |    30 |   0 |         0 |        0 |          0 |   01/10/2014 |
|  7 |    30 |   0 |         0 |        0 |          0 |   01/11/2014 |
|  5 |    30 |   0 |         3 |        4 |          3 |   01/09/2014 |
|  4 |    30 |   1 |         3 |        2 |          3 |   01/08/2014 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d31a3/5)** demo

Answer (score 2):

Try this............

```
SELECT  min(Id) Id, Total, New, Completed, Assigned, Unassigned, CreatedDtUTC
FROM TblUsage 
GROUP BY Total, New, Completed, Assigned, Unassigned, CreatedDtUTC
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 for your appreciable response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(Id) AS Id, Total, New, Completed, Assigned, Unassigned, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC, 101) AS CreatedDtUTC
FROM TblUsage 
GROUP BY Total, New, Completed, Assigned, Unassigned, CreatedDtUTC
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/136cb/2)

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | TOTAL | NEW | COMPLETED | ASSIGNED | UNASSIGNED | CREATEDDTUTC |
|----|-------|-----|-----------|----------|------------|--------------|
|  1 |    29 |   1 |         5 |        6 |          5 |   01/07/2014 |
|  4 |    30 |   1 |         3 |        2 |          3 |   01/08/2014 |
|  5 |    30 |   0 |         3 |        4 |          3 |   01/09/2014 |
|  6 |    30 |   0 |         0 |        0 |          0 |   01/10/2014 |
|  7 |    30 |   0 |         0 |        0 |          0 |   01/11/2014 |
```